# Windows Files does not open when click in webpage "Select file". Selenium Python

Tags: python, database, selenium, file

So, I need to upload a file to a page. When i click on the input button (and it clicks without error), windows files to search for the file i need, does not open.
Here its my code snip. and what i need to be open at click

```
#IMPORTAR DATOS
selec = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@name="IMPORT_FILE"]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", selec)
time.sleep(2)
```

[![windows files][1]][1]

THANKS!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHktU.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `pyautogui` via `pip` and do this.

```
import pyautogui
... # set the webdriver etc.
...
...
element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@title='Open file selector']"))  # Example xpath

WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(element_present).click() # This opens the windows file selector

pyautogui.write('C:/path_to_file') 
pyautogui.press('enter')
```

Comment: thanks! it didn't gave me any error but the windows files never opened and the file hasn't been uploaded!

Comment: I resolve it this way selec = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@name="IMPORT_FILE"]')

time.sleep(2)
selec.send_keys('C:/ETL/Contact/datos.csv')

pyautogui.press('enter')

Comment: Oh..Sorry..i didn't see your comment before. Glad it worked out.